# Get a value from map stored in struct

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

I have a trouble for gonna get a value from map stored in struct. Please, look at the next part of code (some strings skipped):

```
type Settings struct {
     ...
     LcInfoData     *[]LcInfodb   
     LcInfoLog      *MapLcInfoLL
}
type MapLcInfoLL map[string]LcInfoLL
type LcInfoLL struct {
     EnableLog   string
     FileLogPtr  *os.File
}
... 
func updLogInfo(cnf *Settings)(err) {
   for _, t := range *cnf.LcInfoData { 
       fpPtr, err := logInit(t.FilepLog);
       if err != nil {
           exitMsg(1, err.Error());
       }
       lcMapVal := LcInfoLL{EnableLog: t.EnableLog, FileLogPtr: fpPtr}
       lcMap[t.LocationID] = lcMapVal 
   } 
   cnf.uLcInfoLog(&lcMap)      // at the end
   ...
}
```

At the end I got filled structure for using in another function (it's global settings). But. I can't get an access to elements inside a map (which stored in structure). I mean something like that:

```
v := *cnf.LcInfoLog["index"]
log.Println("ABOUT LOCATION: ", v.FileLogPtr)
```

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: voting to close as the code that doesn't work isn't shown.  Which is a shame for me coz I was hoping to answer a nice easy question :)

Comment: Of course this works. But you check for nil before dereferencing the value. Why are you storing pointers to maps and slices anyway. That's almost never necessary. https://play.golang.org/p/t_vI3GtzTEv

Comment: Sorry for my trash-code! I'm newbie in Go and have no enough practice for understanding of all niceties.

Comment: Can I ask for the more detailed description? In my sorry I can't apply an example to my sources :(

Comment: @WhiteDruid `v := (*cnf.LcInfoLog)["index"]` <- first dereference the map pointer, then index the map.

Comment: @mkopriva, thank you so much!!! :)